# A difficulty in understanding a question in Ch.1 Israel Gohberg.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

The question and a correction to it is given in the following picture:

[image]

But I could not understand what does the writer mean by the coordinates 3.2.1/2 and 4.3.1/4 inthe vector z, could anyone explain this for me please?

Thanks!

Comment: In some places, at some times, it is/was customary to write the multiplication dot on the baseline (and often, the decimal vertically centred). $3.2.\frac{1}{2}$ means $3\cdot 2\cdot \frac{1}{2}$ here, etc.

Comment: why the author did not cancel the 2 in the numerator with that in the denominator ?@DanielFischer

Comment: So that one can better see the structure of the coordinates, $$\frac{(k+2)(k+1)}{2^k}\,.$$ That's less than obvious if one writes $(2,3,3,\frac{5}{2}, \frac{15}{8},\dotsc)$.

Comment: yeah I can now really see better the coordinates, thank you so much @DanielFischer